# How to load routes from DB in Meteor before everything?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I have this code to create routes from database in Meteor:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe("routes", function() {
    Routes.find({}).map(function(route) {
      try {
        Router.route(route.path, {
          name: route.name,
          waitOn: function() {
            var subscribes = [];
            if (typeof route.subscriptions== 'object' &&
              route.subscriptions
              .length > 0) {
              route.subscriptions.forEach(function(subscription) {
                subscribes.push(Meteor.subscribe(
                  subscription));
              });
            }
            return subscribes;
          },
          action: function() {
            this.render(route.template);
          }
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error: " + e);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

So when I type in browser a path to a route from db gives this error:

Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url: "https://localhost:3000/menus."

I think its because this code runs after pageloads. How can I work around it?

Comment: you probably need the base route to be defined at the minimum and subscribe to the other routes there... but likely if you point to a route before you go through the base route, you will still get the error. 
If your routes are after login, you could load the other routes on after login I guess.

Comment: I have the base route defined and I need before login all routes in that collection be must be defined